# Detect if User modified a dll that is used by your program

Tags: c#, dll

so recently i noticed many programs getting cracked because friends of mine/small developers had .dll's as references which source code was public, and then people recoded that dll and added a debugging system so everything the program does gets printed out to a console while running. I want to find a way to check if a dll got modified by a user/isn't the exact same as the dll i included at the beginning. Any help is appreciated.

```
private bool check()
        {
            bool flag = false;
            string dllname = "dllname";
            string str = "1a720eff0feeb58484180c0f01a774ba";
            AssemblyName name = (from assembly in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
                                 where assembly.Name.ToLower().Equals(dllname.ToLower())
                                 select assembly).FirstOrDefault<AssemblyName>();
            if (name != null)
            {
                string location = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(name.FullName).Location;
                if (!(location != string.Empty))
                {
                    return flag;
                }
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(location))
                {
                    return flag;
                }
                byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(location);
                if (BitConverter.ToString(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "").ToUpper().Equals(str.ToUpper()))
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }
```

Comment: Let me google that for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=Detect+if+User+modified+a+dll+that+is+used+by+your+program&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @roryap ye, but all postings where using a api atleast i remember so, so i asked her to know if theres a way to code it and run it when the programm gets launched... ima add a coding me and my friend tried to the OP(didn#T work, buti think its in rthe rigth direction)

Answer (score 0):

Sign your assemblies with a key? The strongly-named assemblies are automatically checked on load (if I understood you).

[Creating and Using Strong-Named Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwb8f617(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name:
[Strong-Named Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx)